# Moved Wordpress website to root directory, now getting http 400 Bad Request errors

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-400

URL: http://www.tmla.org/athletics/

Tried reuploading the images and no luck. Never encountered this before. Anyone know why this is happening?

```
    "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://www.tmla.org/wp-content/plugins/slideshow-gallery/vendors/timthumb.php?src=wp-content/uploads/slideshow-gallery/5.jpg&w=960&h=424&q=100&a=t"

    timthu...100&a=t

    "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://www.tmla.org/wp-content/plugins/slideshow-gallery/vendors/timthumb.php?src=wp-content/uploads/slideshow-gallery/7.jpg&w=960&h=424&q=100&a=t"

    timthu...100&a=t

    "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://www.tmla.org/wp-content/plugins/slideshow-gallery/vendors/timthumb.php?src=wp-content/uploads/slideshow-gallery/4.jpg&w=960&h=424&q=100&a=t"
```

Comment: Try de-activating the `slideshow-gallery` and then re-activate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the server has a very limited amount of space. It was near capacity which meant images couldn't cache. Made some room and it's all gravy now.